# Huge Performance Cost to using SQL Server ORDER BY clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is causing a query to take longer if we have an ORDER BY clause at the end?

If I run the query without Order BY it takes a split second, but throw the ORDER BY on and its MINUTES!!

Is there a known reason for this?

```
SELECT top 100 a.UniqueID
    ,a.SomeID
    ,a.ContentID
    ,SortOrder
    ,b.ValueOfMine
INTO #ContentHistory
FROM widgetHistory.dbo.CustomerProductContent a WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN widgetHistory.dbo.ProductContent b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.ContentID = b.ContentID
LEFT JOIN widgetHistory.dbo.SomeThings k WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.SomeID = k.SomeID
LEFT JOIN widgetHistory.dbo.SubscriptionContents c WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.ContentID = c.ContentID
    AND c.SubscriptionID = k.SubscriptionID
WHERE c.ContentStatus = 'GO'
ORDER BY UniqueID
```

It wont even complete so I cannot view the execution plan..

Comment: does the UniqueID field have an index?

Comment: As David hints at, a proper set of indexes can mitigate much of the performance hit.  What is proper for your application is highly dependent on the specific usage.

Comment: @DavidStetler I am not sure, I have it open in Design mode - How do I check for INDEXED? SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Comment: @DavidStetler I will look into it since its out of the scope of the question. Pluralsight.com has some tuts.

Comment: And why the NOLOCK hints? Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without the `ORDER BY`, SQL Server will give you the first 100 rows it computes as soon as it's done computing them.

With the `ORDER BY`, SQL Server must compute all rows, sort them, and only then can it give you the 100 rows you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

As SQL is set-oriented, I think that you would be better off creating your temporary table and then using your order by when you query the result set from the temporary table.  Tables by definition do not have a default ordering, so you are always better off to use the Order By clause when you actually want to query the data rather than when you are posting the data.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, I will apply that knowledge.